# Proof that $\|Ax\|<\|x\|$ for $A$ with absolute value of eigenvalues $<1$

Tags: proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to prove that if all eigenvalues of the square matrix $A$ are $|\lambda|<1$ then $\|Ax\|≤\|x\|$. This seems like a simple proof but I fail to understand how to relate the basic understanding that $Av=\lambda v$ to it.

Comment: should be $Av = \lambda v$ ? how about setting $x = v$ as eigen-vector.

Comment: The statement is not true. Consider the matrix with $2$ in one off-diagonal entry and zeros elsewhere. All eigenvalues are $0$, but the norm is $2$.

Comment: @Yimin You can't "set" $x$ to something, if the statement is to be proved for all $x$.

Comment: Did you leave out some hypotheses, e.g. that $A$ is hermitian?

Comment: No I didn't, correction* not a proof but a true/false.

Comment: oops, misunderstood the problem.@NormalHuman. if $A$ is real symmetric, hermitian, then eigenvector will become a basis, then it is possible to show that.

Comment: @user296769 Well, now you know it's false, and my comment tells you how to give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true.  As an example (per NH's comment above), note that
$$
\pmatrix{0&0\\2&0} \pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{0\\2}
$$